# Populate table with values from another table based on both rows and columns

Tags: r, dataframe, populate

I have an empty data frame that looks like that:

```
df <- data.frame(Hugo_Symbol=c("CDKN2A", "JUN", "IRS2","MTOR",
                          "NRAS"),
                 A183=c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                 A240=c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                 A330=c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

I would like to use a larger data frame to populate the previous one. The structure of the larger data frame is the following:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Hugo_Symbol=c("CDKN2A", "JUN", "IRS2","MTOR",
                          "NRAS", "TP53", "EGFR"),
                 A183=c(2.3, 3.3, 2.6, 4.7, 1.2, 5.7, 3.4),
                 A240=c(1.3, 2.3, 4.6, 5.7, 2.2, 7.7, 1.4),
                 A330=c(0.3, 2.3, 1.6, 1.7, 4.2, 1.7, 4.4),
                 A335=c(1.3, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 0.2, 0.7, 0.4),
                 A345=c(0.3, 4.3, 4.6, 4.7, 4.2, 4.7, 0.4))
```

My desired output should look like that:

```
Hugo_Symbol A183 A240 A330
1      CDKN2A  2.3  1.3  0.3
2         JUN  3.3  2.3  2.3
3        IRS2  2.6  4.6  1.6
4        MTOR  4.7  5.7  1.7
5        NRAS  1.2  2.2  4.2
```

I tried to use `dplyr` package, specifically `semi_join()` function, but it returns empty table to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use a join

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- names(df)[-1]
df[nm1] <- lapply(df[nm1], as.numeric)
setDT(df)[df2, (nm1) := mget(paste0('i.', nm1)), on = .(Hugo_Symbol)]
```

-ouptut

```
df
   Hugo_Symbol A183 A240 A330
1:      CDKN2A  2.3  1.3  0.3
2:         JUN  3.3  2.3  2.3
3:        IRS2  2.6  4.6  1.6
4:        MTOR  4.7  5.7  1.7
5:        NRAS  1.2  2.2  4.2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  left_join(df2, by = "Hugo_Symbol") %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with(".x"), ~ coalesce(.x, get(gsub(".x", ".y", cur_column()))))) %>%
  select(Hugo_Symbol, ends_with(".x")) %>%
  rename_with(~ gsub(".x", "", .), ends_with(".x"))

  Hugo_Symbol A183 A240 A330
1      CDKN2A  2.3  1.3  0.3
2         JUN  3.3  2.3  2.3
3        IRS2  2.6  4.6  1.6
4        MTOR  4.7  5.7  1.7
5        NRAS  1.2  2.2  4.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to just drop the NA columns from the first data frame? If so, a left join will produce the desired output.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Hugo_Symbol = c("CDKN2A", "JUN", "IRS2", "MTOR",
                  "NRAS"),
  A183 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  A240 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  A330 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  Hugo_Symbol = c("CDKN2A", "JUN", "IRS2", "MTOR",
                  "NRAS", "TP53", "EGFR"),
  A183 = c(2.3, 3.3, 2.6, 4.7, 1.2, 5.7, 3.4),
  A240 = c(1.3, 2.3, 4.6, 5.7, 2.2, 7.7, 1.4),
  A330 = c(0.3, 2.3, 1.6, 1.7, 4.2, 1.7, 4.4),
  A335 = c(1.3, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 0.2, 0.7, 0.4),
  A345 = c(0.3, 4.3, 4.6, 4.7, 4.2, 4.7, 0.4)
)

library(dplyr)

left_join(df["Hugo_Symbol"], df2, by = "Hugo_Symbol")
```

Answer (score 1):

one more way to do it-

- `left_join` on `hugo_symbol`
- then use `transmute` `across` on those columns only which either end in suffix `.y` and `hugo_symbol`
- retain values as such.  hence `~.`
- remove `.y` from names using `.names` argument.  use regex `[.]y` so that is not interpreted as wildcard and y.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% left_join(df2, by = 'Hugo_Symbol') %>%
  transmute(across(Hugo_Symbol | ends_with('.y'), ~., .names = '{gsub("[.]y", "", .col )}'))

#>   Hugo_Symbol A183 A240 A330
#> 1      CDKN2A  2.3  1.3  0.3
#> 2         JUN  3.3  2.3  2.3
#> 3        IRS2  2.6  4.6  1.6
#> 4        MTOR  4.7  5.7  1.7
#> 5        NRAS  1.2  2.2  4.2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This is very clever!